# Resizing a partition on El Capitan 10.11.6?

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I want to remove both `disk0s4` and `disk0s5` partitions which were created for a bootcamp install. However when I goto disk utility then try to remove the partitions from my drive, I get the following error: `MediaKit reports not enough space on device for requested operation.`

Screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

Here is what I get when I run `diskutil list`

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            425.6 GB   disk0s2
3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
4:                  Apple_HFS Untitled                73.4 GB    disk0s4
5:         Microsoft Reserved                         16.8 MB    disk0s5
```

After I run the command `sudo gpt -r show disk0` :

```
      start       size  index  contents
         0          1         PMBR
         1          1         Pri GPT header
         2         32         Pri GPT table
        34          6         
        40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
    409640  831297360      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
 831707000    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
 832976536  143274344      4  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
 976250880     262144         
 976513024      32768      5  GPT part - E3C9E316-0B5C-4DB8-817D-F92DF00215AE
 976545792     227343         
 976773135         32         Sec GPT table
 976773167          1         Sec GPT header
```

I would like to keep all data currently on the Macintosh HD, if someone could help me remove the `untitled` and `microsoft reserved` partitions, that would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The command below should remove `disk0s5`.

```
sudo diskutil erasevolume "Free Space" "" /dev/disk0s5
```

The command below should remove `disk0s4`.

```
sudo diskutil erasevolume "Free Space" "" /dev/disk0s4
```

The next command expands your Macintosh HD volume (`disk0s2`) to contain the free space. This command will also automatically move the Recovery HD volume (`disk0s3`) to the end of the drive.

```
sudo diskutil resizevolume /dev/disk0s2 R
```

> Note: I am not sure if the prefix `sudo` is necessary. (But, it will do no harm if you include the `sudo`)

There are more complex steps that can be employed to remedy your problem, but I will not post these steps unless the one of the commands given above fails to work.

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

1. Click on the partition to be deleted
2. Click the minus button (cannot see if that is what you did)
3. Click Apply

[image]

Comment: ??? The MS reserved partition is a **16.8 MB** slice, so no files to lose! But examining the partition map I would assume that the whole Boot Camp setup is hosed and your proposal won't work.